# Re Out of Memory exception while running SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, ssrs-2008, out-of-memory, ssrs-2008-r2

I am creating a report with requirement to select all parameter values(have 3 parameters)

But, when I am running this report it throws System Out of Memory exception.

I tried selecting few values but even that doesnt work.

Any suggestions how can I avoid this?

```
Dataset 1: 
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8
from storedproc
WHERE col1 IN ('A')
AND col2 IN (1) 

Dataset 2:

SELECT DISTINCT col3
FROM  storedproc
WHERE        (col2 = @col2)

Dataset 3:
SELECT DISTINCT 
col1, col3,
col4 COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT + ' - ' + col5 COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT + ' - ' + col6 COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
 + '   ' + CONVERT(char(5), col7, 108) + ' - ' + CONVERT(char(5), col8, 108) AS Alias_col
FROM        storedproc
WHERE        (col2 = @col2)
```

Comment: please check the log file - it will show you more details for this cause. then other thing is create same report in separate page again bind there with top 10 rows it should be working. if not works then show us your query so we can help you in this case.

Comment: @pedram - where can I find the log file?

Comment: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS11.SQLEXPRESS\Reporting Services\LogFiles`

Comment: @pedram - please find queries above. I am using stored proc as source let me know if u need anything else

Comment: I don't think I have enough points to join discussion....

Comment: yes please I am stuck with this exception and cannot progress...

Comment: can you please show me the log error message? also have you tried by making separate report? please gimme answer of both question in one comment. thanks

Comment: No, I cannot find log files path..I will do separate report now...

Comment: Yes. Please try that. Also you need to check log files for more information if you will get error again. let me know on which path did you check in your pc?

Comment: I cannot fine Program Files folder in my PC for this path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS11.SQLEXPRESS\Reporting Services\LogFiles

Comment: in which drive you have installed OS? It must be there. bye I'm leaving will check tomorrow... :)

Comment: I ran the query from Dataset1 in backend and it returns around 495323 rows...

Comment: so you mean your dataset returns 495323 rows but not showing on report. can you please try to put just one textbox and set expression like `="Number of rows: " & CountRows("DatasetName")` - if it returns this count then there must be some problem with the data and datatype. we need to more check on this.

Comment: No I ran the query in SSMS and I see the result but I get exception when I run report. Textbox shows 51567. I have also observed yest that when I deploy the report to report server it does not show any errors. This only happens from visual studio :(

Comment: hmmm it's strange. simply try by fetching top 1 records and bind to table see it works or not?

Comment: Yes, I just tried TOP 100 records from datasets and I don't see any errors from Visual studio...

Comment: okay so it is working fine if we fetch only 100 records right? if yes then try by making some bunch of records and see when error occurs!! I mean in which bunch of records!

Comment: ok will try that after some time. cheers!

Comment: Can you please take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35290886/ssrs-hyperlink-report-with-parameters-not-working-properly

Comment: Yes, I am currently on 16 need 4 more to go...

Comment: I observed I am not getting that error now but will learn to check logs in case...Thanks for your help!

Comment: you are most welcome! :) what you did at last please join this chat room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102894/discuss-on-35252406-issue