# SSRS Hyperlink report with parameters not working properly

Tags: reporting-services, hyperlink, parameters, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

[Main report which drills down to Register URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zG9Mx.png)

I have main report with 3 parameters and have 3 levels of drill downs. The last drill down is to register level and it shows a hyperlink when clicked on it, it should directly take user to register report.

i.e If clicked  on 1st URL – 000018045 – Cert  in Childcare but it takes me to different one as below

[Embedded report in hyperlink](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFKj2.png)

Everything works fine in my report except hyperlinked report which showing different values other than user selected in main report drill down list.

I made sure I am using same parameters in both reports and identical datasets.

Any idea where am I going wrong?

Comment: you need to provide more details. like which link is made and which should be actual? if possible share image here so we can get more idea.

Comment: @pedram please find images above

Comment: Reason can be, your cell may bind hyperlink with other data. (need to check by printing whole URL in separate textbox)

Comment: @pedram: can you please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35315082/scope-parameter-error-in-ssrs-chart

Answer (score 0):

When using the hyperlink action in SSRS you have to encode the URL to handle all the characters. Here's an article that explains it to get you started: http://capstonebi.blogspot.com/2010/04/url-encoding-in-reporting-services.html