# What is causing a scope parameter error in my SSRS chart?

Tags: reporting-services, charts, dataset, ssrs-2008, aggregate-functions

Why am I getting this error in my chart?  ([Chart Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDpnU.png))

I am using this expression in the chart:

```
Series:

=Sum(Fields!Mins_Att.Value)/Sum(Fields!Mins_Poss.Value)

Series 1: 

=Sum(Fields!Mins_Att.Value, 
         "Chart2_CategoryGroup2")/Sum(Fields!Mins_Poss.Value, "Chart2_CategoryGroup2")
```

and I am getting this error:

> The Y expression for the Chart has a scope parameter that is not valid for an aggregate function. 
>       The scope parameter must be set to a string constant that is equal the name of group, data region or name of dataset.

Comment: What is "Chart2_CategoryGroup2" supposed to be referring to? I don't see it anywhere in the screenshot.

Comment: @Steve - you are right I have changed it to current dataset and chart displays now. Thanks for pointing this out

Comment: Glad that helped. I'll move it to the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scope of "Chart2_CategoryGroup2" doesn't exist in the report.